# Office365 mail multiple inboxes

Tags: email, dns, hosting

I hope this is the right place to ask this question. If not, please point me to the right place.

My client has recently upgraded to office365 email service.

So, in the control panel of my website host. I added mx records towards the office365 server. This all works.

Before they transferred, they were using other email addresses next to the main one (info@domein.com)
In the office control panel I can only find a way to add aliases.

What I want is a separate inbox for example jim@domein.com.

This was possible before upgrading to office365. My question is; how can I get this working without having to pay for another email account

Comment: "I hope this is the right place to ask this question.".  It is not, have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic  In short questions here should be related to programming.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So where would be the right place to ask this? @Patrick Mevzek

Comment: Maybe [su] but not sure, read the help section BEFORE posting, to see what is ontopic or not there. Note that there aren't SE websites for absolutely all questions on earth either, some just do not belong anymore. On your case, did you start by asking your website host/email provider/O365 vendor?